# Knockout mapping for nested Complex Objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a viewmodel with child objects. How do I define the mapping for properties of the child objects?

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ManageComparatorSelectionsViewModel ManageComparatorSelectionsViewModel { get; set; }
    public ManageComparatorItemViewModel CurrentComparatorItem { get; set; }
}


public class ManageComparatorSelectionsViewModel
{
    public IList<Edition> Editions { get; set; }
    public IList<Year> Years { get; set; }
}

public class ManageComparatorItemViewModel
{
    public Edition ChosenEdition { get; set; }
    public Year ChosenYear { get; set; }
}
```

I am doing the following to initialize knockout

```
    var mapping = {
        'ManageComparatorSelectionsViewModel.Editions': {
            key: function (data) {
                return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.Id);
            }
        },
        'ManageComparatorSelectionsViewModel.Years': {
            key: function (data) {
                return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.Id);
            }
        }
    };
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModelData, mapping);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

is there any reason you need those to be unwrapped?  you could always get at those same objects by getting the **property()**  or by doing **ko.toJS()** item you are looking at.

EDIT:

For the dropdown:

```
<select data-bind=" template : { 'name' : 'templateID', foreach : optionlist } "></select>
```

With a template that looks like this:

```
<script type="html/text" id="templateID">
      <option value="${ key }">${ text }</option>
</script>
```

Comment: oh, maybe I dont understand the proper syntax. The reason I was trying to set the Id on those arrays is because the dropdownlists seem to be getting needlessly updated even when none of the values in the array change. For instance, if I update my viewmodel and add a value to 1 array, then all the arrays and dropdown boxes get refreshed.

Comment: how are you binding your model to the select list?  select with an options?  because that will cause the refresh every time.  In most cases it's not a problem as it will refresh behind the sense while the dropdown is not being displayed.  However if that doesn't work for you, you could use a template binding.   Updated the main post with how to go about that.